# Can't change tooltip coordinates MFC

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

I need to make tooltip a little bit right and lower to mouse cursor, but i can't do it in any way, tried different coordintaes but nothing seems to work. Where is the problem? Thank you.

```
        // Add the new tooltip (if available)
        if (m_LastToolTipRow!=-1 && m_LastToolTipRow!=-1)
        {
            // Not using CToolTipCtrl::AddTool() because it redirects the messages to CListCtrl parent
            TOOLINFO ti = {0};
            ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
            ti.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_TRANSPARENT; // Indicate that uId is handle to a control
            ti.uId = (UINT_PTR)m_hWnd;  // Handle to the control
            ti.hwnd = m_hWnd;           // Handle to window to receive the tooltip-messages
            ti.hinst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
            ti.lpszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK;
            m_OwnToolTipCtrl.SendMessage(TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFO) &ti);

            m_OwnToolTipCtrl.SendMessage(TTM_TRACKPOSITION, 0, (LPARAM)MAKELPARAM(pt.x + 100, pt.y + 100));
            m_OwnToolTipCtrl.SendMessage(TTM_TRACKACTIVATE, true, (LPARAM)&ti);

            m_OwnToolTipCtrl.Activate(TRUE);
            //Multiline
            m_OwnToolTipCtrl.SetMaxTipWidth(256);
            //m_OwnToolTipCtrl.SetMaxTipWidth(SHRT_MAX);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

TTF_IDISHWND
Indicates that the uId member is the window handle to the tool. If this flag is not set, uId is the tool's identifier.

According to this, the window with m_hWnd handle is the one that shows the tooltip and you can position the window itself. If you meant a tooltip separate to that window than there is a principal problem there.

Comment: I need to display it relatively to mouse cursor. Anyway, adding TTF_ABSOLUTE doenst work too.

Comment: I changed the answer after realizing that the window handle you provide implies the tooltip is incorporated to that window.

Comment: I'am not really understand what's the difference between tooltip window and tooltip itself.Moreover i can't even imagine how to solve that issue because i'am new at mfc.

Comment: When you provided TTF_IDISHWND the window itself acts as your tooltip. Did you mean the window to be a tooltip?

Comment: I don't know what's the difference. I though tooltip should be anyway displayed relatively to mouse cursor, beacuse i provided coordinates. So i must pass  m_OwnToolTipCtrl HWND to uId in order this to work? I tried to get a handler with GetSafeHwnd() but it still doesnt work.

Comment: This is how to create a tooltip for some dialog:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Just take that dialog HWND and pass it to CreateToolTip function. Then you will be able to move window given hwndTip.

Comment: Thats more compilcated, i'am using class for displaying tooltip for list control cell.

Comment: There is a ready to use function, give it a window handle (is control cell a window as well?) and the function will produce the tooltip window you want and you will be able to move it. It is Win32 API. MFC is just a wrapper. I use Qt. But I did do Win32 and MFC some years ago.

Comment: >is control cell a window as well? I think not.

Comment: Just pass to CreateToolTip the hwnd of the window you think has that cell in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78589/discussion-between-ivan-petrov-and-alexandervx).